# Proper type hints in Python 3.7 for number types and sympy

Tags: python, types, sympy

I'm writing code to represent geometric objects and have been using Python 3.7's @dataclass decorator to create immutable objects. Something like:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Vector:
    x: float
    y: float
```

This was great until I started mixing in sympy. I would like to be able use a symbol for x or for y and let duck typing in the methods handle the fact that +  now means something different. However, I don't want to lose typing for x and y. I think that I *could* do this:

```
from typing import Any
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Vector:
    x: Any
    y: Any #incidentally, can I declare an uninitialized class attr without a type?
```

but it would be much more awesome if there was some union type stored somewhere I can't find in sympy that is a sort of float or sympy object type. Does this exist? What is the pythonic or proper way of doing this?

My best guess right now is:

```
TNum = TypeVar('TNum', int, float, sympy.core.expr.Expr)

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Vector:
    x: TNum
    y: TNum
```

What's the best practice here?

Comment: `x` and `y` have to have the same type within a single instance of `Vector`, correct?

Comment: I think you just need to have `Vector` extend `Generic[TNum]`. What you have now would allow `x` and `y` to have different types within the restricted set of allowed types.

Comment: Can you just use the SymPy geometric objects? e.g. `Point(1, 2) + Point(2,3) -> Point(3, 5)`.

Comment: @chepner Technically I want x and y to be allowed different types, since one coordinate could be an unknown and one a symbol. So, I want to be able to do things like u = Vector(x, 5), v = Vector(7, x), and then solve u.dot(v) == 0 for x (for example).

Comment: @smichr No, those were just a simple example to get the point across. I'm actually working in several geometries with lots of different geometric object types, different metrics, not just points, and higher dimensions. The built-in sympy objects are far too limited.

Comment: @John Oh, then I think what you have is the right way to do it.